# Bypass SuperSpeed USB3.1 lines around USB2.0 Hub

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I found [this](https://numato.com/help/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/USB3.0-FPGAHostCommunication.pdf) document online, which shows an interesting USB routing topology that I have not seen before.  The 4x superspeed lines go straight from the USB3 connector to the SuperSpeed IC, but the USB2.0 lines go off to a USB2.0 hub, where one of the down stream ports connects back up to the SuperSpeed IC.  I can't find any other examples of this online... is this allowed?  I would have probably just designed in a USB3.1 SuperSpeed hub, and not split the signal lines off.

Comment: Clearly it works. Seems quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

This design uses one USB 2.0 channel for the high-speed data channel of USB 3.0 and another for FT2232 for jtag/uart/spi for programming and debugging.

Traditionally FT2232 is usually connected a independent USB 2.0 port, but this design multiplexes it into the main USB port using a USB 2.0 Hub IC.

Super-speed channel is not split because FT2232 is a full-speed chip and can not make use of the super speed channel.

> But in the proposed FPGA host interface scheme,
>   instead of connecting the USB 2.0 signals (D+/D-) directly to the
>   upstream connector, a USB hub (USB2422 – A 2-  Port USB 2.0 Hi-Speed
>   Hub Controller from Microchip Technologies) is inserted in between.
>   This allows the USB2.0 bus available on USB C connector to be shared
>   between FT601 and the FT2232H USB 2.0 FIFO bridge acting as the
>   sideband processor (See figure 3   below).    In this scheme, the SPI
>   signals available on FT2232H Bus A are connected to the SPI bus used
>   for FPGA configuration. A General Purpose IO on this bus is also
>   connected to PROG_B of the FPGA to allow the host to reset the FPGA.
>   Optionally,  additionally available General Purpose IOs on FT2232H can
>   be used to monitor the FPGA configuration progress by observing the
>   DONE signal.

This solution works because the high/full/low-speed channel and super-speed channel work independently and not simultaneously on one endpoint, so the FT601 chip either sees itself directly connected to the super-speed channel, or to the high/full/low-speed channel via a hub. One more hoop in the high/full/low-speed channel than the super-speed channel is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

USB3 endpoints (upstream-facing ports) are allowed to have only standard (LS/FS/HS), only SuperSpeed, and of course, both.

USB3 downstream-facing ports must support standard and SuperSpeed, or standard only, but *not* SuperSpeed only. This is to allow backwards compatibility with legacy LS/FS/HS devices.

Further, you can’t ‘split’ a USB3 downstream facing port into two endpoints, one SuperSpeed and one standard. It is only allowed to negotiate a connection to one device. To split it, a hub is required.

Comment: Can you clarify your last point?  It sounds like you are saying this shouldn't work.

Comment: It’s not an allowed topology under USB3 rules. It will not do the negotiating with USB3 correctly. It would work only with USB2.